# Tips for managing safe and insecure PC mixes

Tags: networking, security, vlan, local-area-network, pfsense

There are two buildings connected by an optical fiber, each with 3-10 PCs but in a mix of PCs used in a business context and some in homes.
Unfortunately, when the network was designed years ago, no one took steps to keep the two environments separate.

**Building A**
There are servers, printers, work PCs, guest PCs, personal smartphones.
*Here is also the only Internet connection* used by both buildings.
It was solved with a firewall (pfsense) separating the office LAN and a network segment with a different Access Point for smartphones and guest PCs. There are two DHCPs to keep the two networks separate.
I would like guests to be able to use the working printers on the LAN and I don't know if a rule in the firewall will suffice.

**Building B**
Here, too, there are printers, work PCs, smartphones and guest PCs.
Here there are also homes with personal PCs, xBoxes, SmartTVs, etc.
Only the DHCP of the LAN in Building A is used
**So with more security problems** and therefore I need to separate the three environments (works, guests and homes) without modifying the network cabling.
I don't know if it is enough to create VLANs, in any case to connect to the Internet or to the servers in Building A the traffic must always pass through the single fiber.
It must also be taken into account that we have no management possibilities in the houses. There is a network point, but we don't know how it will be used; therefore the check must take place upstream of the network point.
Here, however, I could mount a second pfsense firewall.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: vlans are a good starting point and imho a good start specifically when the printer should be used from both sides

Comment: This may be more of a [security](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) than a system management problem - In any case, you need to more clearly specify the *goals* of your rearchitecturing work - do you just need to ensure that unmanaged devices can less easily saturate your link (reliability)? Or do you suspect that some work PCs are setup in a manner where they derive trust from the untrusted network topology (then that should be fixed first, with measures to limit untrusted machines ability to send spoofed traffic being strictly secondary).

Comment: As I said, I don't have control over personal PCs and smartphones.
In Building A I can limit access via a dedicated Access Point.
But in Building B I have no control and therefore I cannot know if, at his home, an employee on his personal PC is downloading a file with a virus or if his son is trying to enter the corporate NAS using his father's password .
It seems ridiculous to talk about this, but today this is the network configuration and first I have to segment the physical network so that only the internet access is free and everything else is confined within that network segment.

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume that all the PCs and printers are connected to managed switches that are VLAN-capable.  If that is not the case, there is little you can do until you change that.

At each site, create three VLANs:  Work, Home and Guest.  Trunk the 3 VLANs across the fiber link and to the firewall, so the firewall is the default gateway for each VLAN.

You can then assign each port to the correct VLAN, depending on the type of device on that port.

Now you can create policies on the firewall to isolate each VLAN.  As a start, I suggest you allow all VLANs to reach the Internet, but don't allow devices in one VLAN to reach another. That way, you can keep home and business devices separate.